# Latex subsection Counter

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am having some problems with subsection counters on Latex:

I want to keep counting the number of the subsection

1. Section 1

1.1 Subsection 1

2. Section 2

2.2 Subsection 2

Comment: `\counterwithout*{subsection}{section}`

Comment: If I saw this in a publication my reaction would be that it had not been properly proof read as the **2.1 Subsection** was missing. However, of course, it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your preamble

```
\counterwithout*{subsection}{section}
```

*If* you get an error, then follow these steps:

1. Update your TeX system
2. If after the update you still get an error, add also `\usepackage{chngcntr}`

*Caveat.* Your readers will be puzzled by the strange numbering system.